# I am unable to update to different mutable arrays while processing a big array using par_iter()

Tags: arrays, rust, mutable, rayon

A large array of structs to be processed and two different mutable arrays should hold the values.

I used par_iter and got the following error:

```
fn par_calculate_depreciation_for_assets(assets_to_depreciate: &Vec<Depreciation>) -> Result<(), Ferror> {
    let mut acc_dep = 0;
    let mut errors: Vec<String> = vec![];
    let mut assets_record : Vec<AssetRecord> = Vec::new();

    assets_to_depreciate.par_iter().for_each( |item| {
        
        let result = calculate_monthly_depreciation(item);
        
        if result.is_err()
            {
                errors.push(item.asset_code.clone());
         
            }
        else
            {
                let (asset, depreciated_asset) = result.unwrap();
                build_csv_struct(item, &mut assets_record, asset);
            } 
    });
    
    append_to_csv(assets_record);
    dbg!("Errors {:?} unprocessed", errors);
    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `errors` as mutable, as it is a captured variable in a `Fn` closure
  --> src/services/csv_services/dep_for_all_assets_in_csv_copy.rs:69:17
   |
69 |                 errors.push(item.asset_code.clone());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you currently see is that `errors` is mutably captured by your closure implementing the [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) trait you pass to the `for_each` call on your parallel iterator, which Rust does not allow.

There is a more fundamental problem with your current implementation, though. There is a race condition. What happens if two threads simultaneously try to add an element to `errors`? You must make sure that access to `errors` is mutually exclusive. I can really recommend reading the shared-state concurrency section of the Rust book: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch16-03-shared-state.html.

Here a minimal example that fixes your error and the race condition, by wrapping `errors` in a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#):

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

use std::sync::Mutex;

fn par_calculate_depreciation_for_assets(assets_to_depreciate: &Vec<u8>) -> Vec<String> {
    let errors: Mutex<Vec<String>> = Mutex::new(vec![]);

    assets_to_depreciate.par_iter().for_each(|item| {
        let mut errors = errors.lock().unwrap();
        errors.push(item.to_string());
    });

    errors.into_inner().unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let errors = par_calculate_depreciation_for_assets(&vec![0, 1, 2, 3]);

    assert_eq!(
        errors,
        vec![
            "0".to_owned(),
            "1".to_owned(),
            "2".to_owned(),
            "3".to_owned()
        ]
    )
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0c7a3e80986e7e49e21dee6fb75a6d6)

Comment: Thank you , this worked. Apologies for the delay in replying.